# Google Map doesn't load second time in JQuery UI dialog

Tags: jquery, google-maps, jquery-ui

In the OnClientClick of Button in my ASP.Net Application, I call this function to show a JQueryUI dialog with Google Map Inside. Everything works well for the first time. But, Second time, the map seems to be blank with gray background, But, every other controls inside map are shown. This is my code. Is there any method to dispose the map on close, so that I can reload map again on next button click.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
function loadMap()
{

       var currentMapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng($('#<%=txLatitude.ClientID %>').val(), $('#<%= txLongitude.ClientID %>').val()); 
       var mapOptions = {
            center: currentMapPosition,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap-dialog"), mapOptions);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentMapPosition,
            map: map,
            title: 'SubProject Location'
        });
       //collects New Location, and closing dialog on click
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            var latitude = e.latLng.lat();
            var longitude = e.latLng.lng();

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: e.latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'SubProject Location'
                });
                // Center of map
                map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));
                $('#<%= txLatitude.ClientID %>').val(e.latLng.lat() ) ;
                $('#<%= txLongitude.ClientID %>').val(e.latLng.lng() ) ;

               $("#gmap-dialog").dialog('close');
        });

          $("#gmap-dialog").dialog('open');
}
</script>
```

The problem is same as this [live demo](http://wecodeyoursite.com/samples/GoogleMaps/google-map-on-jquery-dialog.htm). 
If you load the map second time, It will be gray. I checked it in Chrome, IE, and Firefox.

Comment: What do you mean by 2nd time? are you hiding the map? if so you would need `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` when you show the maps again.

Comment: Yes... It's in dialog naa. The user may close the dialog or he will click on map to select a location

Comment: resize doesn't help. Its again the same. @kaho

Comment: The problem is same as like this live demo. 
http://wecodeyoursite.com/samples/GoogleMaps/google-map-on-jquery-dialog.htm
If you load the map second time, It will be gray. I am using Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I found out the answer. The problem is initializing map object more than once. I globally declared the map variable, and initialized only once using a condition, and it's perfectly working now.

```
 var map = ''; 
 function loadMap()
 {

       var currentMapPosition = new google.maps.LatLng($('#<%=txLatitude.ClientID %>').val(), $('#<%= txLongitude.ClientID %>').val()); 
       var mapOptions = {
            center: currentMapPosition,
            zoom: 14,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        if(!map){
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap-dialog"), mapOptions);
        }
        else{
            map.setOptions(mapOptions);
        }

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: currentMapPosition,
            map: map,
            title: 'SubProject Location'
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            var latitude = e.latLng.lat();
            var longitude = e.latLng.lng();

                  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: e.latLng,
                    map: map,
                    title: 'SubProject Location'
                });
                // Center of map
                map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));
                $('#<%= txLatitude.ClientID %>').val(e.latLng.lat() ).attr('class', 'modified-textbox');
                $('#<%= txLongitude.ClientID %>').val(e.latLng.lng() ).attr('class', 'modified-textbox');
                  $('#<%= saveButton.ClientID %>').attr('class', 'save-button');

               $("#gmap-dialog").dialog('close');
        });

          $("#gmap-dialog").dialog('open');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Moses, you saved my lot of time :)